# Push-forward of nef divisors via finite morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, birational-geometry, intersection-theory, divisors

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a finite morphism between smooth projective varieties, and let $D$ be an effective nef but not ample divisor on $X$.

Consider the divisor $f_{*}D$ on $Y$. Is $f_{*}D$ nef but not ample as well ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you want $f$ to be surjective, otherwise $f_*D$ is not defined. Then $f_*D$ is nef: for any curve $C\subset Y$, $\ (f_*D\cdot C)=(D\cdot f^*C)\geq 0$.   But it might very well be ample. Consider a smooth quadric $Q\subset \mathbb{P}^3$, and let $f:Q\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ be the projection from a point outside $Q$. Let $D$ be a line contained in $Q$. Then $D$ is nef, not ample, but $f_*D$ is a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$, hence ample.

Comment: I have a question. Why does the formula $f_{*}D\cdot C = D\cdot f^{*}C$ hold? If $X$ and $Y$ are surfaces it is the projection formula but why does it hold in general? Thank you very much.

Comment: @user125056: The projection formula holds in any dimension.

Comment: Yes but the version of the projection formula I know is this one: $f^{*}D\cdot C = D\cdot f^{*}C$. The divisor is pulled back and the curve is pushed forward.

Comment: Have a look at a book on Chow rings, e.g. Fulton.

Comment: Do you mean Fulton - Intersection Theory?

Comment: Yes, in particular chapter 8.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.